# QtCreator: What is the best way to print strings to the terminal?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt-creator, terminator

I am learning to use Qtcreator on lubuntu 17.10, and want to print some output to the terminal. I've had trouble, so have stripped my program down to a basic *Hello World* to print a single string to the terminal. Currently, I am using this code:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    std::cout << "HELLO WORLD" << std::endl;
    return a.exec();
}
```

My .pro file contains these lines which look like they could influence the terminal behaviour:

```
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++11 console
```

I also have 'Run in terminal' checked in the Run Settings.

This builds without issue. When I run it, the terminal pops up(I am using `terminator`), and is blank, with a blinking cursor. To get the string to appear, I have to press `<Enter>`. The string appears, but the program doesn't end. I don't get the "Press enter to close the window" type message in the terminal that would indicate the program has ended, and I must close the terminal 'manually'. Also, in the Application Output window, it says:

```
/home/user/path_to_my_program crashed.
```

Presumably because I force close the terminal. I would really like to figure out why it's not printing the string to terminal and exiting cleanly.

**The terminal after I press ENTER(blank beforehand):**

[image]

Comment: I think we really need to see all the project files.  How did you create the project: QtCreator or command line with qmake?

Comment: @Marker I created the project in QtCreator, as a Qt console app

Comment: @Marker Not sure what other files you mean.. The rest of the .pro file just has the main.cpp source listed, and an option to do with warnings when using something deprecated

Comment: Output is buffered. Generally a newline or `endl` will flush the buffer, or you can use `std::flush` if you like.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thanks. It does have the effect of making the output appear without the need to press Enter... although oddly, it doesn't work every time.. but doesn't change the need to force close the terminal.

Comment: Your app doesn't terminate the way you expect because you call [`a.exec()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#exec) -- it's waiting to process events.

Comment: @G.M. Yes! Returning 0 and getting rid of a.exec() works!

Comment: In that way you didn't really make a Qt application .. when you GET RID of a.exec() ... then also get red of  `QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);` .. you end up with a c++  `main()` with a couple of commands .. Also in Qt practice is use `qDebug()` to print to terminal .. that should solve your first issue

Comment: @MohammadKanan Getting rid of QCoreApplication a(argc, argv); made the program not work at all. Even though I wasn't using a at all..

Comment: No, I can do that

Comment: You might missed run Qmake again?

Answer (score 0):

This is normal for a Qt console  Application. It is running a messageloop and exactly doing what it should.
To send text to the console you can use std::cout, qout or qDebug(). The latter is used for debugging. More information can  be found here. It also contains the pittfalls you run into. [Qt console Application](http://lubby.org/ebooks/qtconsoleapp2/qtconsoleapp2.html)